# 2010 honda cr v. When you turn headlamps off they stay on

Tags: honda, electrical, headlight, crv

2010 honda cr v se the headlight stay on. And some times  come on when parked.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: I'll guess (that's why it's not posted as an answer) that the car has a defective headlight relay.

Comment: What country is the car licensed for? There are a whole lot of weird lighting rules tied to regulations, e.g daytime running lamps (DRL) parking lights which turn on when turn signal is engaged and key off, etc...